# Powershell json parsing error cannot bind argument to parameter

Tags: powershell, rest

I am working on an use case where I have to pass json input parameters to a rest api endpoint which triggers execution of a powershell script in the backend. This powershell script now needs to parse the json input parameters and assign these values to the variable for execution. I am able to pass the input parameters to the rest api endpoint but not sure how to parse the input variables.

***Powershell to invoke rest api***

```
 # Job Execution Powershell
    
 $token = "abc123"
 $header = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $token
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
 }
    
 $sid = "sid"
 $rg = "rgname"
 $azautoaccount = "azautoaccountname"
 $job = "jobname"
 $runbook = "test"
 $Uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$sid/resourceGroups/$rg/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/$azautoaccount/jobs/$job" + "?api-version=2019-06-01"
    
 $json = @"
 {
     "properties":{
         "runbook":{
         "name":"$runbook"}
     },
  "parameters":{
         "VmName" : "TestVM",
         "ResourceGroup" : "$rg"
         }
 }
 "@
    
 Invoke-WebRequest -Method PUT -Uri $Uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Body $json
```

***Powershell Code that rest api runs in the backend***

```
 # Runbook Powershell
    
 Param(
      [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [object]$json
 )
    
 # Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
 Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
    
 # Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity
 $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
    
 # set and store context
 $AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
    
 # Convert object to actual JSON
 $json = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
    
 # Use the values from the JSON object as the parameters for your command
 Start-AzVM -Name $json.VMName -ResourceGroupName $json.ResourceGroup -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

***Error:*** `cannot bind argument to parameter 'inputobject' because it is null convertfrom-json`

Comment: Well is the `$json` input params value `$null` ? :) unless the script is being called from powershell where `$json` is already an `[object]`, i would just set it to `[string]`

Comment: How does the JSON passed via `-Body` translate into a call to your script on the backend?

Comment: @Otter, I tried `[string]` and that returns no value. All the input parameters have some value no `null`.

Comment: @mklement0, Do you have an example of how to do that?

Comment: @mklement0, I am working using this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/runbook-input-parameters#start-a-runbook-using-the-rest-api-and-assign-parameters)

Comment: @ITHelpGuy, i think what we are trying to get at, is how are you executing/calling the second script in your question? Show us the code that is calling that script

Comment: @Otter, In the code block invoke rest api where I call the `PUT` method that is basically running the second block of code in the OP. First block of code fires the execution of second block of code.

Comment: ok, and how is that service calling your script? it would be really useful to see the code that is calling your second script

Comment: @Otter, unfortunately I have no idea either how that the service call executes behind the scenes.

Comment: im afraid that service may be passing NULL, can you write out the $json object to host to confirm it is not null?